# Partitions on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a m3.medium instance, with a volume of 20GiB, type standard.

When I run `sudo fdisk -l`, it shows:

```
Disk /dev/xvda1: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
```

But when I run `df -h`, it shows:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  7.7G  172M  98% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

I'm confused. Where are the remaining 10GiB?

Comment: I understand you've created and attached an EBS volume as your root device (please confirm) Most likely the responsible is AMI image you're using, since it's quite usual these AMIs are restricted to a specific size (i.e. 8GB) If that's the case, you should create two EBS volumes. One for root (i.e 8Gb) and the other for aditional storate. What kind of image are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` and now my partition has 20GiB